# How to make javascript run smooth on Galaxy S3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, galaxy

I have a javascript game that has 15 divs moving around. It works smoothly on my desktop and my iPhone but when I test it on Galaxy S3 it looks really jerky. The weird thing is that it runs at 60 FPS on both devices. How do I make it smooth on the Galaxy S3? It's like it's running the code to change the "left" of the div 60 times per second but it doesn't always visibly do it.

I've tried adding transform3d to the divs but that just makes it worse.

http://curtastic.com/test5.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    <body style='margin:0;width:640px;'>
        <div id=fps></div>
        <style>
            .block {
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                -webkit-perspective: 1000;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var blocks = [];
            var angle=0;

            var fpsFrames = 0;
            var fpsTime = 0;

            function gameLoop() {
                var now = new Date();
                fpsFrames++;
                if (now - fpsTime >= 1000) {
                    $('#fps').html("FPS: "+fpsFrames);
                    fpsFrames = 0;
                    fpsTime = now;
                }

                var block;
                for(var i in blocks) {
                    block = blocks[i];
                    block.x += 3;
                    if (block.x >= $(window).width()-50) {
                        block.x = 0;
                    }
                    block.canvas.css('left', block.x);
                    block.canvas.css('top', block.y);
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var block;
                for(var i=0; i<15; i++) {
                    $("body").append("<div id=block"+i+" style='position:absolute;width:33px;height:33px;background:green' class=block></div>")
                    block = [];
                    block.canvas = $('#block'+i);
                    block.x = Math.random()*($(window).width()-50);
                    block.y = Math.random()*($(window).height()-50);
                    blocks[i] = block;
                }

                window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
                  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
                          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                          function( callback ){
                            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                          };
                })();


                (function animloop() {
                    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
                    gameLoop();
                })();

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use css transition rather than js for moving things. CSS transitions are GPU optimized while js is all CPU. I can recommend http://rekapi.com/ as an api for this.

Comment: I need to support IE 9.I don't know why that phone won't let me use javascript at 60 fps, I can use a ton more CPU before it goes down to 50 fps.

Comment: I tried switching to transitions but the same problem happened. 60 FPS but looks really choppy compared to iPhone. http://curtastic.com/test5t.html